# Postgres INSERT from Source (2 columns) into Target (3 columns)

Tags: insert

I am using workbench to create my tables in redshift.My source table dw_subscription has two columns and target testschema.subscription has three columns. This is the piece of code

INSERT INTO testschema.Subscription
(subscriptionrowdate, customerid, subscriptionid)
SELECT  top 100    customerid, subscriptionid
FROM dw_subscription;

I want to do insert some values into the subscriptionrowdate (target table) but since source table doesnt have this column, how do go on about assigning a value to the column subscriptionrowdate from SOURCE script?

e.g SOURCE TABLE

SELECT  top 100   if subscriptionid is null then subscriptionrowdate =subscriptionid +1,
customerid, subscriptionid FROM dw_subscription;

Any ideas? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Achieved the above by

Comment: achieved the above by scripting as following :SELECT  top 10 
  '0000-12-12' as subscriptionrowdate,
  '0000' as subscriptionrowlog....